# So many parenthesis. I really can't wrap my head around all these parenthesis

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

Why are there two sets of parenthesis here?

```
return state.filter(({ id }) => {
            return id !== action.id    
    });
```

I'm having such a tough time wrapping my head around this one statement! Why can't it just be:

```
return state.filter({ id }) => {
            return id !== action.id
        };
```

Anyone that can even try helping me would be awesome!

Comment: The first one "filter ()" if for the filter method the second one "()=>" define a function

Answer (score 3):

If you use like the second example you gave, the syntax would be wrong. You are closing the parenthesis immediately after the `filter` statement.

In the first example actually code is something like that:

```
return state.filter( (someObj) => {
            return someObj.id !== action.id    
});
```

But to shorten this, we are destructuring the id parameter. Like this:

```
const { id } = someObj;
```

[See here more about destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

In the function arguments we do this like:

```
( { id } ) => { ... }
```

Here we are directly picking up the `id` property from the argument object.

And above this there is the `filter`'s parenthesis. So:

```
filter( ( { id } ) => { ... } )
```

Answer (score 3):

In your second example you write `{id}` as being an argument of `filter` but `filter` takes as argument a callback function that is written this way

```
(arg) => {/*my code*/;}
```

so take that piece of code and place as an argument make this result

```
myFunction((arg) => {/*my code;*/})
```

you can also do

```
myCallback = (arg) => {/*my code*/;}
myFunction(myCallback);
```

also I guess you will get a syntax error as the main part of your function is simply written without arguments.

here is your first example with a bit of spacing between the parentheses for better understanding of the logic:

```
state.filter(  ({ id }) => {return id !== action.id} );
```

One other way of writing that would be

```
state.filter(  function({ id }){return id !== action.id}  );
```

Is that clearer?

Comment: I like the translation to the older style you provided at the end.  I was going to do the same and I am glad someone did as I think it helps clarify things.